Is anonymous/low-rep post feedback no longer collected?
When viewing the monthly post feedback stats in the 10k tools on Stack Overflow, I noticed there is no data:

This happens for it being set to "day", "week" and "month".
Then, I went to SEDE and wrote a query giving me the newest entries in the PostFeedback table. The last entry on both Stack Overflow and Super User seems to be from the middle of May (~17. of May).
In my opinion, the anonymous/low-rep post feedback was useful for identifying a few different kinds of posts, e.g. questions related to recent/ongoing events or finding outliers overall.
Was that feature removed deliberately (in order to get them to sign up?) or is this a bug? Can we get that information back in some way (at least low-rep feedback if you really want to show the sign-up modal for people when clicking on a vote button)?
And even if you don't give us these stats back, is there much of a point in keeping the parts of the 10k tools page that just show NaN?
Update
It seems to be available again since 26.8.2024.

Given that they no longer tell you that your feedback was collected when you vote anonymously, but rather shove a big login page in your face without any context, I'd say it was very deliberate.

@TylerH What if you're registered on the site already but don't have the required 15 or 125 reputation to vote? Anonymous feedback was still collected in this case.

We do also have some unusually low drops Apr24-Apr28 and Apr30-May07 at least on Stack Overflow. Making it likely that it corresponds to some sort of A/B Testing. Though I can't find a specific announcement for that. Could also be a result of moving some things over behind CloudFare?

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog For downvoting, the old modal is still there for logged in users, at least on other network sites. I can't test upvoting anywhere as I have the association bonus, and I have more than 125 reputation on Stack Overflow so I can't test downvoting there while logge din.

so... is the question now why it stopped being collected for an unannounced(?) period?

I asked it with the intention of possibly getting some reasoning on why it stopped/hopefully getting it fixed. It seems like the data is available now but I don't know of any staff response for that. I don't know whether it still needs to [status-review] tag but I don't think I should remove mod-tags (I didn't check whether I can).

@dan1st you can't, only mod or staff can add/remove red tags. Anyway, since there's no response, it might be temporary and the data can be gone again any moment, we can't know. So best wait for staff to respond, or at least change the tag to [tag:status-completed].

I think we're best waiting for an official response on this one.

Well, to be honest towards Stack Overflow (the company), this was just a test to begin with, as Jeff announced 13 years ago in Anonymous user feedback now in testing.
So looks like the test is finally concluded, just a bit sad the company chose to do that without sharing with the community any results of the test, insights, or the reasoning behind shutting it down.

It was "in testing" like how Gmail was "in beta" for ~12 years (AKA production)

@TylerH well, sure - and most SE sites are in "beta" for long years as well, it's just a technical detail. But my point is, it was never officially launched as actual feature.

@TylerH or like how SE network sites were permanently "in beta", awaiting a graduation redesign
